# Formatting pyplot major and minor label's distance from axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting some `datetime` objects on an `xaxis` of `matplotlib`'s `pyplot`.
 However there is some minor text overlap.

I would like to move **`xaxis.major_locator()`** a bit to the bottom of the page.

As you notice in my image, 09/27 overlaps with 00 a bit.  **I would like to eliminate that.**

[image: graph output]

Here is my code at this time.

```
daysfmt = DateFormatter("%m/%d")
hourfmt = DateFormatter("%H")
ax.plot_date(x,y, label=ptforruc.getSource(),fmt='-')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(daysfmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(hours)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(hourfmt)
ax.autoscale_view()
x = ptforeta.getDates()
y = ptforeta.getValues()
plt.plot_date(x,y,label=ptforeta.getSource(),fmt='-')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05,1),loc=2,borderaxespad=0.)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This shall help you make it happen as you wish:

```
for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.tick1line.set_markersize( 0 )
    tick.tick2line.set_markersize( 0 )
    # ------------------------------------------------
    # a demonstrator code, not a production one
    # -------------------
    tick.label1.set_horizontalalignment( 'center' )
    tick.set_pad( 2.5 * tick.get_pad() )
```